# Product quantity more than 10 it shows only 0 left on product page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

I'm using Magento 2.4.2

if the Product quantity is more than 10 it shows only 0 left on the product page. less than 10 will show the true quantity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you checked for what it shows for salable quantity? Is it greater than 0?

Comment: @RahulBarot
yes Default Stock : 44

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Magento 2.4.2 inventory-configurable-product-frontend-ui module.

Until a fix is released if you do not use the stock threshold options you can safely disable this module which will stop the "only 0 left" message from appearing.

See this issue for more details and workarounds :

https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/3276